# How to make babel-plugin-transform-imports work

Tags: reactjs, plugins

I use  babel-plugin-transform-imports as following to decrease the file of lodash when "import _ from 'lodash'" but it doesn't help.

What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

please replace my-library with `lodash`. You took the example in documentation too seriously.  :)

```
"plugins": [
    [require('babel-plugin-transform-imports'), {
        'lodash': {
            transform: function(importName, matches) {
                return 'lodash/' + importName;
            },
            preventFullImport: true
        }
    }]
]
```